Does the Fermi surface drift opposite to electrons in an electric field?
I have encountered somewhat of a paradox when it comes to electrons in an electromagnetic field. I hope someone here knows where the problem lies.
Upon minimal coupling of a free classical electron gas to the electromagnetic field, the Hamiltonian acquires the form
\begin{equation}H = \frac{-\Delta}{2m} \rightarrow \frac{(\nabla + ie\textbf{A})^2}{2m} -e \Phi\end{equation} for a wave function that transforms as $\psi(x)\rightarrow e^{-ie\chi(x)}\psi(x)$ and $A \rightarrow A +\nabla \chi$.
Then for a gauge $\Phi = 0$ (i.e. I have restricted my gauge freedom to time-independent gauge transformations) and a spatially homogeneous electric field, that is $\textbf{A}(x) = \textbf{A}(t)$, the Schrödinger equation (in first quantisation) is solved by a plane wave solution like
\begin{equation}\psi(x) = e^{-i(\epsilon_{\textbf{k}} t + e \textbf{v}_k\cdot\int_0^t\textbf{A}(t')dt' + e^2/2m*(\int_0^t\textbf{A}(t')dt')^2- \textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{x})}\end{equation} or something of that shape. In any case, the velocity is given by $\textbf{v} = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \textbf{k}} = \textbf{k} + e(\textbf{A}(t)-\textbf{A}(t_0))$.
On the other hand I would expect that the Fermi surface is centred around the lowest energy state which was $\textbf{k}=0$ before the electric field is turned on but then becomes $\textbf{k}_{min}(t)= -e\textbf{A}(t)$ since it minimises the dispersion parabola shifted to the left by $e\textbf{A}$, $\epsilon_{\textbf{k}+e\textbf{A}}$. Then since the Fermi surface is symmetry around the lowest energy state the average momentum of the electrons will shift $\langle \textbf{k}\rangle = 0 \rightarrow -e\textbf{A}$.
What confuses me is that the average velocity seems to be shifted in the opposite to the velocity that a single electron should have in the electric field.
Thank you in advance for anyone who tries to resolve my confusion.

It looks like you might have a sign mistake in your definitions of the fields. $\vec E=-\partial_t\vec A$

I am not sure what you mean. The force on a particle of charge $q=-e$ is $\textbf{F}=q\textbf{E}=(-e)(-\partial_t \textbf{A}) = e\partial_t\textbf{A}$, hence the momentum is the integral of this $\textbf{k}(t) = \textbf{k}_0 + e(\textbf{A}(t)-\textbf{A}(0))$. I am pretty sure that's correct.

I think your notation conventions are a bit weird, and it does seem like maybe the final results are ok. I have no idea where you obtained that $\left<\vec k\right>\to-e\vec A$, or how you asserted that it is the minimum in energy there, or whatnot, but it does seem like you have an equivalent of Equation (41) of http://www.phys.nthu.edu.tw/~spin/course/104F/Kittel-Chapter%206-Tina.pdf and so you ought to be able to get the correct results.

So my idea was, and maybe this is exactly the problem, that if my dispersion changed from $\xi_{\textbf{p}}$ to $\xi_{\textbf{p}+e\textbf{A}}$, the Fermi distribution would be $n_F(\xi_{\textbf{p}+e\textbf{A}}) = n_F((\textbf{p}+e\textbf{A})^2/2m - \mu)$. So whereas before the minimal coupling the argument of the Fermi distribution would take on it's minimum at $\textbf{p}=0$, this would now be the case for $\textbf{p} = -e\textbf{A}$.

Also I am not sure what you mean by weird notation conventions. Maybe you are referring to the sign of the gauge field part in the Hamiltonian? This comes down to how you define the gauge transform of the field/operators. Keeping in mind, that the creators need to gauge transform contravariantly to the wave function in order for the state to be gauge invariant, I chose the convention, such that the wave function of a mode with charge $q$ transforms with $e^{iq\chi}$, hence the creator has the opposite behaviour. I hope this clears things up.
